# What would make someone lose site collection admin rights and disappear from all SharePoint Groups at the same time every day?

Tags: 2007, permissions, groups

We have someone who has been a site collection administrator for years and is suddenly losing site collection admin rights at 3PM each day. The person also disappears from all SharePoint Groups that he or she was a member of. Ideas?

We can restore the person as an admin right away - the person is still in AD, the My Site doesn't go anywhere, and there's nothing in the security audit logs about the removal.

Comment: Do they have a user profile in the SSP after they are deleted?

Comment: The issue stopped as mysteriously as it began.

Comment: The user was still visible in All Users - is there a different way of seeing which profiles are in SSP?

Comment: Ahh Gremlins....

Comment: I think we should consider closing this question as "Too localized" since this seems like a very unlikely issue and is no longer reproducible.

Comment: I am having a very similar issue and cannot find any solutuion! Hope mine will stop too

Answer (score 1):

Is there a timer job that is scheduled to run at that time? I wonder if there are any third party solutions that have been installed on your environment that would mess with user accounts

Comment: No add-ons or timer jobs that our admins could find but the investigation ceased when the issue stopped occurring.

Comment: Great place to look though - thanks.